# vmware fusion heavily interferes with displaylink manager on macbook with m2 chip

Tags: macbook-pro, virtualization, vmware

I'm running a macbook pro with m2 chip. In order to get to use multiple monitors instead of just one I've attached a dockingstation to my mbp. I'm also using the display link manager application to support the dock.

Ever since i configured that setup everything just worked like a charm.

I'm running a linux distribution on vmware fusion. Using the vm also worked well until several hours ago. When I try to run my virtual machine it starts to kill the display link manager.

Although it kills the manager all monitors (2 external + 1 mbp) remain intact but can't be accessed as internally there's only one registered monitor.

I know that display link manager might run with issues. I'm just confused as everything went smooth until today. Only yesterday i used that vm for several hours without encountering any issues.

Has anyone had the same issues with vmware fusion and display link manager on a macbook with m2 chip (or any other silicon processor)?